# Troubleshooting login hooks on OS X

Tags: macos, login

I have a lab of iMacs on OS X 10.6.8 that are used with network accounts. I have created the following login hook:

```
#!/bin/sh
#make local workspace on Storage HD
mkdir /Volumes/Storage\ HD/Users/$1/WorkSpace

#Fix owner and permission for the User
chown -R $1 /Volumes/Storage\ HD/Users/$1/WorkSpace
chmod 700 /Volumes/Storage\ HD/Users/$1/WorkSpace

#Create Symlink from new location created to Desktop folder
ln -S /Volumes/Storage\ HD/Users/$1/WorkSpace afp://server.foo.private/User/$1/Desktop/WorkSpace

#Make iMovie folder on storage HD
mkdir /Volumes/Storage\ HD/Users/$1/iMovie\ Events.localized

#Fix owner and permission for the User
chown -R $1 /Volumes/Storage\ HD/Users/$1/iMovie\ Events.localized
chmod 700 /Volumes/Storage\ HD/Users/$1/iMovie\ Events.localized
```

However, I am having some trouble getting the login hook to work. I want it to accomplish the following two tasks:

1. Create a local workspace where students can work with data in media applications (ProTools, Final Cut Express etc.), and make a link on the users desktop.
2. Create a location on the client's Storage partition for iMovie data to reside. Users will be educated that the iMovie data stays on the particular machine it was imported too.

How can I do that?

Comment: What exactly is not working? Is the loginHook not executed at all? Did you register the login hook? Are the permissions set correctly? Or are some of the commands executed and others not? What do the system logs say?